# Validate XSD with XML using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, xsd

please tell me how to parse or validate XML with XSD using JavaScript?

Comment: Not to mention this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223873/validate-an-xml-against-xsd-with-js-jquery

Answer (score 2):

If it's client-side (in-browser) Javascript, I'm not aware of any XSD validator that runs in the browser. I would create a server-side validation service and invoke it from Javascript as a web service.

Answer (score -2):

You can't do it, unless you are OK with the validation working only in internet explorer. If that's fine please check this: http://technosatish.blogspot.com/2008/06/javascript-xsd-validation-and-examples.html

Comment: The statement "You can't do it, unless you are OK with the validation working only in internet explorer" is probably wrong. Furthermore, answers are more valuable if you explain how one might go about implementing your suggestion rather than just posting a link.

Comment: Not precise enough maybe: No Javascript XSD validator exists, the only tool I am aware of that will do it is MSXML2 run via ActiveX and is IE exclusive. The link pasted provides full code of the validator working in IE, including an example.